# click detected on the following div on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a  link in my code

```
<a id="guest-link-button" href="#" class="btn btn-blue clipboard-copy" data-target="#guest-link">COPIAR</a>
```

it works on a pc screen but on mobile or when the screen is minimized to mobile size the click event is detected on the next div not in the link.

Comment: Can you please add some informations so that your case can be reproduced? Like the CSS styling, the surrounding HTML code, and maybe on which mobile/browser you see this behaviour?

Comment: The problem its on mobile is setting the browser size on pc or on a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

if you do this :
`<a> <div></div> </a>`
the div will be a clickable link, but if you put the anchor tag `<a>` inside a div e.g. `<div> <a></a> </div>` the div will not be clickable.